# How do you set the Kerberos ticket lifetime from Java?

Tags: java, kerberos

In my krb5.conf file, I have configured the ticket lifetime to 10 minutes (`ticket_lifetime = 10m`) for testing purposes. When I `kinit` from the command line and then run `klist`, I see that the ticket lifetime is 10 minutes. However, when I login from Java code, it seems that the ticket lifetime in my krb5.conf file is ignored and the default lifetime of 1 day is used. I have set `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` and can see that my custom krb5.conf file is being loaded, yet the `ticket_lifetime` does not seem to be honored. Is this a limitation of the Java Kerberos implementation, or is there some other way to set the ticket lifetime from Java?

Comment: To really understand how  Java processes your Kerberos/JAAS config, you should set `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`

Comment: If you want to learn a few nasty things about JAAS, have a look into https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jaas.html and https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jdk_versions.html (these chapters are not specific to Hadoop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with any currently released version of Java. Java 9 will honor the ticket_lifetime and renew_lifetime configurations. This OpenJDK ticket has more info: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8044500